# Azure AppInsights not tracking all Requests

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

i have configured appinsights during build time using nuget and the app insights tracks my request only for a specidifed period of time stops tracking my request after that and live stream also replicates the same behaviour
if i restart or publish the service again it works for another certain amount of time and after that it comes to a standstill
is there any settings that i need to configure to track all the time ?
will appinsights work only for a services which is always in a hot mode?

***I have intialised my Telemetry in Global.asax file***

***my insights.config file***

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings">
  <TelemetryInitializers>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.HttpDependenciesParsingTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.AzureRoleEnvironmentTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.AzureWebAppRoleEnvironmentTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.BuildInfoConfigComponentVersionTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.WebTestTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.SyntheticUserAgentTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web">
      <Filters>search|spider|crawl|Bot|Monitor|AlwaysOn</Filters>
    </Add>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ClientIpHeaderTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.OperationNameTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.OperationCorrelationTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.UserTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.AuthenticatedUserIdTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.AccountIdTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.SessionTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
  </TelemetryInitializers>
  <TelemetryModules>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.PerformanceCollectorModule, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector">
    </Add>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.QuickPulse.QuickPulseTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.DeveloperModeWithDebuggerAttachedTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.UnhandledExceptionTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.UnobservedExceptionTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.RequestTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.Web">
      <Handlers>
        <Add>System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler</Add>
        <Add>Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.Tracing.RequestDataHttpHandler</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.StaticFileHandler</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.Optimization.BundleHandler</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.Handlers.TraceHandler</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.Services.Discovery.DiscoveryRequestHandler</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.HttpDebugHandler</Add>
      </Handlers>
    </Add>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ExceptionTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
   </TelemetryModules>
  <TelemetryProcessors>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.QuickPulse.QuickPulseTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
      <!--<MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>5</MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>-->
    </Add>
  </TelemetryProcessors>
  <TelemetryChannel Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.ServerTelemetryChannel, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel" />
 <!-- This key is for Application Insights resource 'trhyr' in resource group 'thytry' -->
  <!--<InstrumentationKey>dfgtdhfjtyujytjuti</InstrumentationKey>-->
</ApplicationInsights>
```

***Global.asax file***

```
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.DisableTelemetry = false;
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(TelemetryKey); //Fetched from Application Settings
```

Comment: Can you please share on which platform are you running your service? Is it an Azure Web App or is it a custom service you are running in a VM? Thanks

Comment: I am deploying c# code in azure webapp

Comment: Could you please tell us more about your web app information? Do you enable the web app's always on? It looks like there are no request send to your web app, so the applnsights doesn't work. I suggest you could firstly check the live stream's online server number when the appinsights doesn't track the request.Like this image:http://imgur.com/a/Ar37h.

Comment: @BrandoZhang-MSFT hi,Always on is enabled;Whenever i restart or deploy the service as u suggested the live stream server's count will be one and after sometime it changes to no server online even though i continuously make a call to the api

Comment: According to your description,  I have created a test application using the appinsights, yesterday. It works well. I suggest you could create a new application and enable the appinsightst. If it still show this error, I suggest you could share the application on the github for us to repro the issue.

Comment: @BrandoZhang-MSFT i have changed the telemetry processors  in insights.config file` 
  <!--<MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>5</MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>-->
    </Add>` <br/> I have commented out `<MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>' and it was active for a long time than the usual time,but it too went off idle after long period and wen i made a call again it dint became active again

Comment: Since I couldn't see your insight's config and your application. Now I couldn't repro your issue. I guess maybe your application hang after a period of time. Does the request you send to the api has response? Besides, as I says, I suggest you could share a demo or the  insight's config for us to repro your issue.It will be more easily for us to find the reason.

Comment: @BrandoZhang-MSFT I have shared my config file ,pls look into it

Comment: According to your codes, I suggest you could find the TelemetryKey from your insight and set the TelemetryKey  in the insight's config. Un-comment this code: <!--<InstrumentationKey>dfgtdhfjtyujytjuti</InstrumentationKey>-->.

Comment: @BrandoZhang-MSFT I am initializing the instrumentation key in global.asax file;so why do i need to declare the key again in config file too

Comment: I'm so sorry that I didn't see your update the global file. Does your web application has multiple requests?  If your application sends a lot of data and you are using the Application Insights SDK for ASP.NET version 2.0.0-beta3 or later, the adaptive sampling feature may operate and send only a percentage of your telemetry.  I suggest you could try to switch off adaptive sampling, remove the [AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-sampling#adaptive-sampling-at-your-web-server) node from applicationinsights-config.